# Как обрабатываются запросы к БД с несколькими условиями?

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста: если в запросе несколько условий, например, `WHERE a=1 AND b=2`, то сначала выбираются данные, удовлетворяющие условию `a=1`, а потом среди них выбираются данные по условию `b=2`? Или для второго условия поиск идет опять по всей таблице? Целесообразен, конечно, первый вариант, но что-то нигде не нашел явного подтверждения.

Comment: Нет гарантий порядка проверки условий, всё будет выполнено так, как решит оптимизатор http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484135/select-where-clause-evaluation-order

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev, спасибо за информацию

Comment: В качестве оффтопика замечу, что, например, про sqlite3 я где-то читал, что порядок имеет значение

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Зависит от индексов и изобретательности оптимизатора. Ну и надо понимать, что разработчики базы, как правило, достаточно опытные люди.

Проверить всё это можно, запустив `EXPLAIN` вашего запроса.

### Если индексов на эти поля нет

**...то надо принять решение**: делать по две проверки в одном проходе или два прохода по одной проверке. Если данные целиком помещаются в кэше процессора (*почти нереальный случай*), то разница заметна не будет.

Если не помещаются, то **в кэш** будут последовательно загружаться разные участки проверяемого набора данных **из оперативной памяти** (если набор данных туда помещается). Загрузка в кэш занимает какое-то микровремя, но оно становится тем больше, чем больше таблица. Делать два прохода выходит уже дороже: на прежний объём сравнений нужно сделать вдвое больше загрузок в кэш.

Если данные не помещаются даже в оперативную память, всё совсем очевидно — **загрузка с диска очень долгая**. Настолько, что остальные части запроса вряд ли будут заметны, и выполнение двух обходов, скорее всего, примерно вдвое увеличит время выполнения запроса.

***Итог:*** обход один, две проверки на каждый ряд выглядят рациональнее со всех сторон.

### Если есть индекс на одном из полей

**...то всё очевидно**: сходу есть возможность "дёшево" (по ресурсам) сократить перебираемый набор данных до части таблицы с заданным значением в проиндексированном поле. А уже по этому набору выполнить последовательный перебор  и проверить второе условие.

### Если есть индексы на двух полях

**...то  <s>фиг</s>  `EXPLAIN` его знает!** Более достоверного ответа никто не даст, каждая БД решает этот вопрос как-то по-своему.

Оптимизатор может посмотреть в оба индекса, прикинуть где последовательный перебор окажется меньше и использовать его. А может ошибиться и взять не тот, руководствуясь какими-то своими соображениями.

*PostgreSQL* умеет делать [bitmap scan](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html), в ходе которого он сканирует **оба индекса** и составляет карту (bitmap) по каждому условию, а затем объединяет две карты в одну согласно условиям, получая результат. Но делать ли это, **решает оптимизатор**.

### В идеале: если есть индекс по парам значений

Здесь индекс просто используется напрямую, поэтому порядок поиска будет совпадать с порядком индексирования: сначала спуск с "верхних уровней индекса" (по первому выражению), а затем спуск по второму и **сразу получает ответ**.

### Но всё это неважно, если...

- **данных совсем мало**
  небольшие объёмы данных может быть быстрее обойти без индекса
- **оптимизатор облажается** (что [бывает](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31450503/2076787))
  отладка чего превращается в охоту за индексами путём чтения `EXPLAIN`ов

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ещё про "бывает всякое". Была ситуация с SQL Server, но это даже не принципиально -- думаю, похожая ситуация может быть и с другими СУБД.
Запрос вида (сильно упрощено, в реальности конечно страницы на две):

```
SELECT CONVERT(fielda, INT)
FROM tablea
WHERE ...
```

Поле fielda здесь было текстовым, но условием WHERE гарантированно отрезались все невалидные значения (т.е. такие которые нельзя было преобразовать в INT).
И запрос периодически падал на CONVERT.
Ручная проверка ничего не давала -- выборкой по данному условию было видно, что выбираются валидные значения, и CONVERT работает.
Но тут дело уже в том как сервер БД решает выполнить запрос. Он может взять блок данных и *сначала* выполнить CONVERT, а уже *потом* отрезать лишние строки.

Answer (score 1):

БД выполняет запрос не дословно, на основе запроса составляется план выполнения (query plan), на который будет влиять например наличие индексов. Посмотреть что там в реальности отработает можно через EXPLAIN перед запросом, но его результат еще тоже надо уметь прочитать. На план выполнения можно повлиять в плане джоинов и индексов (FORCE INDEX), но это не полный контроль, в целом оптимизатор БД призван сам решать такие вопросы.