# Влияет ли SQL запрос с заданным условием, на скорость его выполенния?

Tags: mysql, sql

Влияет ли SQL запрос с заданным условием, на скорость его выполенния, если поиск проводится не только по столбцу имеющем уникальный индекс, а и по другому столбцу, у которого индекса нету?

Таблица содержит, больше чем 100 миллионов записей.

Если :

**user_id** - с UNIQUE INDEX

**ban** - без индексов. Может иметь два параметра 1 и 0

```
SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE (`user_id`='41') AND (`ban`='0')
```

Comment: А почему вы не воспользуетесь средствами анализа запроса? Да и просто выполнить запрос так и сяк и посмотреть время?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  А как лучше это сделать? Не подскажите?

Comment: Слишком конечн обширно надо написать чтоб освятить вопрос по анализу именно времени запроса.Самый простой (но уже подустаревший): `set profiling=1;` далее запрос например `select * from table` и далее `show profiles;` покажет что в запросе почем.Еще простой способ из коммента ниже - воспользоваться прогами, где можно сразу видеть время запроса https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/query-profiler.html.....Более сложный вид - анализ профайлов, логов - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-query-profiling  настроить и посмотреть. + Как майк написал в ответе)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  Большое спасибо. Качественно и профессионально.

Comment: Не так давно писал [ответ на похожую тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501187/181100).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оптимизатор в такой ситуации поймает, что уникальный индекс гарантированно выдает не более 1 записи и пойдет именно по пути поиска по индексу, а в довесок потом, когда единственная запись будет выбрана, проверит второе условие. Это конечно если все именно так как вы написали и в запросе одна таблица. Если таблиц больше - надо рассматривать каждую конкретную ситуацию, причем с данными.

Что бы увидеть план выполнения запроса - напишите перед запросом слово `explain`. Если в колонке "keys" будет что то указано - значит он пойдет по этому индексу. Кроме того в колонке "rows" в плане можно увидеть количество строк, которые оптимизатор предполагает просмотреть для поиска результата. При explain рекомендую задавать существующие в базе id, потому что в таком простом случае оптимизатор настолько умный, что заодно заглянет в индекс и может сразу написать в плане, что выборка невозможна, т.к. подходящей записи нет.

Отвечая прямо на ваш вопрос "влияет ли второе условие", да, безусловно влияет, примерно на столько, на сколько влияет проверка одного значения в оперативной памяти одним if. Так что при выборке 1 млн строк по одной штуке таким запросом вы *возможно* сможете заметить изменение, но оно будет исчезающе мало.

Comment: Большое  спасибо. Качественно ипрофессионально.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша таблица не очень большая, и нагрузки на базу нет, то данные запрос на скорость сильно я так думаю не повлияет.

Comment: Таблица содержит, больше чем 100 миллионов записей.

Comment: тогда нужно проводить как уже говорили выше анализ запроса и посмотреть время, я для работы использую DBeaver он при выполнении запроса показывает время его выполнения, как себя ведут другие редакторы не подскажу, но думаю что таже TOAD тоже поддерживает данную функцию